# Linear Layout Background image set alpha

Tags: android

I am using an image as the background of a linear layout in my android program.I need to set opacity for this.Can anyone tell me how can I do this?..The image that is translucent doesnt show the opacity,doesn't know the reason though.
Thanks in advance for your valuable comments

Comment: Can you paste the XML code where you define the background? Do you point to a drawable or directly to the image?

Comment: Please put the code in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to do that...
The significant line is android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: I see... Well I will try to add an answer, maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the background of the LinearLayout programatically this shouldn't be any problem.

What you are looking for is the `Drawable.setAlpha(int alpha)` method. From a personal project:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);
image.setImageResource(R.id.something);
image.setAlpha(110);
```

Not exacly the same, but maybe you get the point.

You are using a drawable as the background of your layout. The challenge here is to get the variable representing your drawable. This is done [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html):

In the activity to the layout:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable background = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.*the id*);
    // The layout which are to have the background:
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.*you get it*));
    // Now that we have the layout and the background, we ajust the opacity 
    // of the background, and sets it as the background for the layout
background.setAlpha( *a number* );
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

And it should work. At least it did work for me.